# How to perform (modified) t-test for multiple variables and multiple models

Tags: python, pandas, data-visualization, t-test, hypothesis-test

I have created and analyzed around 16 machine learning models using WEKA. Right now, I have a CSV file which shows the models' metrics (such as percent_correct, F-measure, recall, precision, etc.). I am trying to conduct a (modified) student's t-test on these models. I am able to conduct one (according to THIS link) where I compare only ONE variable common to only TWO models. I want to perform a (or multiple) t-tests with MULTIPLE variables and MULTIPLE models at once.

As mentioned, I can only perform the test with one variable (let's say F-measure) among two models (let's say decision table and neural net).

Here's the code for that. I am performing a Kolmogorov-Smirnov test (modified t):

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
from pandas import read_csv, DataFrame
from scipy.stats import ks_2samp

results = DataFrame()
results['A'] = read_csv('LMT (f-measure).csv', header=None).values[:, 0]
results['B'] = read_csv('LWL (f-measure).csv', header=None).values[:, 0]
print(results.describe())
results.boxplot()
pyplot.show()
results.hist()
pyplot.show()

value, pvalue = ks_2samp(results['A'], results['B'])
alpha = 0.05
print(value, pvalue)
if pvalue > alpha:
    print('Samples are likely drawn from the same distributions (fail to reject H0)')
else:
    print('Samples are likely drawn from different distributions (reject H0)')
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple solution to my question. It only deals with two models and two variables, but you could *easily* have lists with the names of the classifiers and the metrics you want to analyze. For my purposes, I just change the values of `COI`, `ROI_1`, and `ROI_2` respectively.

**NOTE: This solution is also generalizable.**
How? Just change the values of `COI`, `ROI_1`, and `ROI_2` *and* load any chosen dataset in `df = pandas.read_csv("FILENAME.csv, ...)`. If you want another visualization, just change the `pyplot` settings near the end.

The key was assigning a new `DataFrame` to the original `DataFrame` and implementing the `.loc["SOMESTRING"]` method. It removes all the rows in the data, EXCEPT for the one specified as a parameter.

Remember, however, to **include `index_col=0`** when you read the file OR **use some other method to set the index** of the `DataFrame`. Without doing this, your `row` values will just be indexes, from `0 to MAX_INDEX`.

```
# Written: April 4, 2019

import pandas                       # for visualizations
from matplotlib import pyplot       # for visualizations
from scipy.stats import ks_2samp    # for 2-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test
import os                           # for deleting CSV files

# Functions which isolates DataFrame
def removeColumns(DataFrame, typeArray, stringOfInterest):
    for i in range(0, len(typeArray)):
        if typeArray[i].find(stringOfInterest) != -1:
            continue
        else:
            DataFrame.drop(typeArray[i], axis = 1, inplace = True)

# Get the whole DataFrame
df = pandas.read_csv("ExperimentResultsCondensed.csv", index_col=0)
dfCopy = df

# Specified metrics and models for comparison
COI = "Area_under_PRC"
ROI_1 = "weka.classifiers.meta.AdaBoostM1[DecisionTable]"
ROI_2 = "weka.classifiers.meta.AdaBoostM1[DecisionStump]"

# Lists of header and row in dataFrame
#  `rows` may act strangely
headers = list(df.dtypes.index)
rows = list(df.index)

# remove irrelevant rows
df1 = dfCopy.loc[ROI_1]
df2 = dfCopy.loc[ROI_2]

# remove irrelevant columns
removeColumns(df1, headers, COI)
removeColumns(df2, headers, COI)

# Make CSV files
df1.to_csv(str(ROI_1 + "-" + COI + ".csv"), index=False)
df2.to_csv(str(ROI_2 + "-" + COI) + ".csv", index=False)

results = pandas.DataFrame()
# Read CSV files
# The CSV files can be of any netric/measure, F-measure is used as an example
results[ROI_1] = pandas.read_csv(str(ROI_1 + "-" + COI + ".csv"), header=None).values[:, 0]
results[ROI_2] = pandas.read_csv(str(ROI_2 + "-" + COI + ".csv"), header=None).values[:, 0]

# Kolmogorov-Smirnov test since we have Non-Gaussian, independent, distinctive variance datasets
# Test configurations
value, pvalue = ks_2samp(results[ROI_1], results[ROI_2])
# Corresponding confidence level: 95%
alpha = 0.05

# Output the results
print('\n')
print('\033[1m' + '>>>TEST STATISTIC: ')
print(value)
print(">>>P-VALUE: ")
print(pvalue)
if pvalue > alpha:
    print('\t>>Samples are likely drawn from the same distributions (fail to reject H0 - NOT SIGNIFICANT)')
else:
    print('\t>>Samples are likely drawn from different distributions (reject H0 - SIGNIFICANT)')

# Plot files
df1.plot.density()
pyplot.xlabel(str(COI + " Values"))
pyplot.ylabel(str("Density"))
pyplot.title(str(COI + " Density Distribution of " + ROI_1))
pyplot.show()

df2.plot.density()
pyplot.xlabel(str(COI + " Values"))
pyplot.ylabel(str("Density"))
pyplot.title(str(COI + " Density Distribution of " + ROI_2))
pyplot.show()

# Delete Files
os.remove(str(ROI_1 + "-" + COI + ".csv"))
os.remove(str(ROI_2 + "-" + COI + ".csv"))
```